# Eigen::MatrixXd initialisation

Tags: eigen3

Actually my question is really simple, I'm looking for the most efficient way to construc vector (or ma) from a loop.
In Matlab we do : `M = [1:10]` how to do the same thing in Eigen ?

Comment: Try `LinSpaced` or `setLinSpaced`: http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1DenseBase.html#a5d1ce9e801fa502e02b9b8cd9141ad0a

Answer (score 0):

Thanks chtz, this is actually exactly what I want, so `M=[1:10]` in matlab is equivalent in C++ using Eigen to :

```
Matrix<double,Dynamic,1>          M; //or VectorXd M
M = VectorXd::LinSpaced(9,1,10); // M.setLinSpaced(9,1,10)
```

Comment: Some remarks: `Matrix<double,Dynamic,1>` is the same as `VectorXd`. Instead of the second line you can also write `M.setLinSpaced(9,1,10);`, or you could write the assignment into the line where `M` is constructed. And I assume that the first argument should be `10` and not `9`, if you want to get the same result as in matlab.

Comment: Thanks again chtz.